# Want to remove the blank space below slider images .

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am getting a blank space below the slider images. You can check it http://test.arzeautosales.ca/car/2012-toyota-camry-se . As its a height issue but if i am getting a fix height then its not showing the images properly. So please if anyone can help then let me know .

Comment: may i know which carousel you are using? Your carousel set height according to largest image size, the image with gear box and led screen is tallest image of the slider, so your slider will adjust height according to this.

Comment: if possible, you can use same size images to avoid such issues

Comment: Hi  I am using https://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/connected-carousels/ this slider . Actually these images has different heights so i want to use full heights on images so div resizes according to the height . Is it possible ?

Comment: It is possible, Please check my answer

Comment: give us html and css

Answer (score 0):

you can use padding:

```
<style>
img{padding: -50px}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternative like `Owl Carousel`. you can check demo here https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoheight.html.
 it is also available for wordpress https://wordpress.org/plugins/owl-carousel/. It has the option of auto height which you need for different image sizes.